# Reset influence of neighbour vertices for smooth shading of certain area

Tags: modeling, shaders

I'm doping low poly model for exporting it into the game after (Godot game engine, if it matters). I've met a problem while doing nails for fingers: in "shade smooth" display mode nails are shaded differently.

[image: nail shaded differently from the rest because of smooth shading]

My guess is that happens because of sharp angles formed by "internal" structure. I use double extrusion to make nails (first one is pulled down a bit and behind, the 2nd one extrudes up and upscale (forms a nail plate). Is there a standard or common way to "reset" influence of neighboring vertices on smooth shading of a faces, forming nail surface?

I can guess one possible solution is to make nail unconnected mesh, but is there something like "Crease" for subdivision? Like you mark edges, that limit smoothing though them?

Comment: Have you checked the normals are facing in the correct direction? - Enable the Face Orientation option on the Viewport overlays menu and see if they show in red. If so, select All in Edit mode and use Alt-N > Recalculate Outside to reset them.

Comment: the problem is that while normals themselves are ok. Its smoothing of that double extrusion that breaks stuff. That double extrusion creates invisible small faces that are at sharp angles to one another. And those small edges affect shading of visible surface in a wrong way. 
The approach in [accepted answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/308404/151690)  is what solved it for me.

Comment: Ok. It's always worth checking that if you have problems after extruding.

Comment: Its "did you reset you device" for any shading problem: did you check orientation of normals? did you check for vertex duplicating? XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the combination Auto-Smooth and Weighted Normal Modifier, trimming values, if it suits your needs (you can apply the modifier when satisfied).

[image]

Comment: Yes, that works exactly like I want it too! I might only add that making vertex group with nail and closest neighbors for this modifies makes it even better!